# Change CSS of class in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I've got a class with the display set to `none` I'd like to in Javascript now set it to `inline` I'm aware I can do this with an `id` with `getElementById` but what's the cleanest way to do it with a class?

Comment: Just for future reference, because I think it closely resembles what you want: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript

Comment: @Zirak Unfortunately, that link is broken

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You **can** do that — actually change style rules related to a class — using the `styleSheets` array ([MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheetList)), but frankly you're probably better off (as changelog said) having a separate style that defines the `display: none` and then removing that style from elements when you want them no longer hidden.

Answer (score 17):

Do you mean something like this?

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden-class');
for (var i in elements) {
  if (elements.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    elements[i].className = 'show-class';
  }
}
```

Then the CSS

```
.hidden-class { display: none; }
.show-class { display: inline; }
```

Comment: Claims there's no such method as `getElementsByClassName` for `document`

Comment: Hrm, it's not supported by [older IE](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#fivemethods). I'd honestly recommend something like jQuery, but get bashed every time I suggest it.

Comment: @Zharkus: No harm in recommending using a library as an *adjunct* or postscript to an answer that doesn't require one (said one of the bashers); it's when someone answers a non-jQuery question with a purely jQuery answer that it's in appropriate. @Skizit: A library ilke [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) can smooth over browser differences for you, and provide lots of useful utilities.

Comment: @Skizit: You can add `getElementsByClassName` to browsers that don't support it: http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/

Answer (score 14):

You can use `getElementsByClassName` in which you'll get an array of elements. However this is not implemented in older browsers. In those cases `getElementsByClassName` is `undefined` so [the code has to iterate through elements and check which ones have the desired class name](http://forums.devshed.com/showpost.php?p=2182479&postcount=4).

For this you should use a javascript framework such as jQuery, mootools, prototype, etc.

In jQuery it could be done with a one-liner as this:

```
$('.theClassName').css('display', 'inline')
```

Comment: Wrong, that should be `$('.theClassName').css('display', 'inline')`

Answer (score 10):

you can create new style rule instead.

```
var cssStyle = document.createElement('style');
cssStyle.type = 'text/css';
var rules = document.createTextNode(".YOU_CLASS_NAME{display:hidden}");
cssStyle.appendChild(rules);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(cssStyle);

$("#YOUR_DOM_ID").addClass("YOUR_CLASS_NAME");
```

Answer (score 6):

You may like to exploit/rewrite this function:

```
function getStyleRule(ruleClass, property, cssFile) {
    for (var s = 0; s < document.styleSheets.length; s++) {
        var sheet = document.styleSheets[s];
        if (sheet.href.endsWith(cssFile)) {
            var rules = sheet.cssRules ? sheet.cssRules : sheet.rules;
            if (rules == null) return null;
            for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
                if (rules[i].selectorText == ruleClass) {
                    return rules[i].style[property];
                    //or rules[i].style["border"]="2px solid red";
                    //or rules[i].style["boxShadow"]="4px 4px 4px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

- to scan all style sheets attached pass "" as third argument, otherwise something like "index.css"
- ruleClass contains starting '.'
- if (rules[i].selectorText && rules[i].selectorText.split(',').indexOf(property) !== -1) condition improvement found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16966533/881375
- don't forget to use javascript syntax over css properties, e.g. box-shadow vs. boxShadow

Comment: finally, a good answer:) I edited it and added a "value" input to immediately change the rule

Comment: This was the answer for me as well. Changing the styles of the elements didn't work because some elements are added to the dom via media query (after the event when elements were changed). I'm on a React JS project so the CSS is transpiled into the html. So I had to kill the test for href.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is long gone, here a few remarks:

- Using `display: inline` to make things visible again may spoil the
  page flow. Some elements are displayed inline, others block etc. This
  should be preserved. Hence, only define a .hidden style and remove it
  to make things visible again.
- How to hide: There are (at least) two ways to hide elements, one is
  the above mentioned `display: none` which basically makes the element
  behave as if it was not there, and the `visibility: hidden` which
  renders the element invisible but keeps the space it occupies.
  Depending on what you want to hide, the visibility may be a better
  choice, as other elements will not move when showing/hiding an
  element.
- Adding/removing classes vs. manipulating CSS rules: The result is
  quite different. If you manipulate the CSS rules, all elements having
  a certain CSS class are affected - now and in the future, i.e. new
  elements dynamically added to the DOM are also hidden, whereas when
  you add/remove a class, you must make sure that newly added elements
  also have the class added/removed. So, I'd say adding/removing
  classes works well for static HTML, whereas manipulating CSS rules
  might be a better choice for dynamically created DOM elements.

Answer (score 2):

To change CLASS you need to edit document stylesheets

```
[...document.styleSheets[0].cssRules].find(x=> x.selectorText=='.box')
    .style.display='inline';
```

```js
[...document.styleSheets[0].cssRules].find(x=> x.selectorText=='.box')
    .style.display='inline';
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="box" >My box 1</div>
<div class="box" >My box 2</div>
<div class="box" >My box 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it is to have a hidden class, like so:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

After that, there is a `className` attribute to every element in JavaScript. You can just manipulate that string to remove occurrences of the `hidden` class and add another one.

One piece of advice: Use jQuery. Makes it easier to deal with that kind of stuff, you can do it like:

```
$('#element_id').removeClass('hidden').addClass('something');
```

Comment: Pfft! What's not Javascript about jQuery? ;-)

Comment: The fact that jQuery-specific code doesn't work in plain-vanilla JS, if jQuery isn't included?  "Use jQuery" isn't always a valid answer to every question about JS, and i'm sure some people get tired of hearing it.

Comment: Generally your answer shouldn't introduce jQuery if it wasn't mentioned in the question. If you really want to include jQuery, should answer in vanilla JavaScript and add a "...however, in jQuery, it would look like this:"

Comment: If you bothered reading the answer, you'd see that I go and explain how to do it in vanilla JavaScript, and then, and _only_ then do I recommend jQuery.

Comment: The only JS i see in the answer is jQuery-specific.  If you'd shown an example of how to do it otherwise, i'd probably have upvoted the answer.  (I didn't downvote, but mostly because i feel -1 is enough of a point.)