# Could someone explain why my javascript is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Could someone please explain where i am going wrong on getting my hidden DIV to display using Javascript. I have looked at previous answers to this and they do not seem to be working.

```
        .newinner
    {
        display: none;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        background: white;
        width: 905px;
        margin: auto;
        height: 400px;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    function ShowDiv(newinner)
    {
        document.getElementsByClassName("newinner").style.display="block";
    }
    </script>
```

Below is the DIV

```
    <button type="button" name="faddress" value="Show Div" onClick="showDiv('newinner')" />Find Address</button></div>
    <div class="newform">
    <div class="newinner">
    <form>
    <div class="formtitle"><b>To request this brochure please fill out the form below.</b></div>
    <div class="ntitle"><b>First Name*:</b><br><select>
      <option value="title">Title</option>
      <option value="mr">Mr</option>
      <option value="mrs">Mrs</option>
      <option value="miss">Miss</option>
      <option value="ms">Ms</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="fname">
    <input type="firstname" name="fname" /></div>
    <div class="lname"><b>Last Name:*</b><input type="lastname" name="lname" /></div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't see you calling `ShowDiv` anywhere and there is no element with ID `newinner`.

Comment: One sets the style attribute of an *element* rather than a CSS *selector* (`.newinner`), you can do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753680/change-css-of-class-in-javascript but as the link says, there are better ways. You also dont call the function in your example.

Answer (score 1):

newinner is defined as a class, and you are searching for a node which has id equal  to newinner...
moreover you are not calling ShowDiv() anywhere in the code you posted

**-- Updates --**

I see you've updated the question since my initial answer, but there are still several problems in the code.

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns all the elements with the given class; it's an array-like structure. So normally you've to loop over each element; but in this case you could use an `id` instead, and then the `document.getElementById` method,
that  returns only the selected element when found, or `null` otherwise.

So you can rewrite `showDiv` as:

```
function ShowDiv (id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}

<button type="button" name="faddress" onClick="showDiv('newinner')">
    Find Address
</button>

<div id="newinner">
    ...
</div>
```

Also keep in mind that the use of `onClick` attribute is good for fast prototyping or demo purpose;
if you're going to use this code in production, I recommend you to use [document.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Comment: sorry missed that bit <button type="button" name="faddress" value="Show Div" onClick="showDiv('newinner')" />Find Address</button></div>

Comment: @user1839483: Then please [**edit** your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13491946/edit) and add the relevant information. Code in comments is most of the time horrible and information distributed over comments is not useful either.

Comment: @FelixKling sorry i am new to this :-)

Answer (score 1):

you are not calling the function anywhere in your page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use document.getElementById() method, then give your DIV an ID.

Just change your line 2 from `<div class="newinner">` to `<div class="newinner" id="newinner">`