# Javascript: can not set property style Opacity, TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: javascript, css, opacity

I have the following code. I added the last line, and the var mytest = on line 3,  and want to set the opacity to 0.3

```
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.classList.add('hotspot');
var mytest = wrapper.classList.add('info-hotspot');
mytest.style.opacity = 0.3;
```

Unfortunately getting the following error on line 4.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

In CSS I have defined the opacity as 0.6 and I want to change it to 0.3

Anyone got advise or a clue?

thx,
Joost

Comment: Set the style on `wrapper` not `mytest` ?

Comment: `.classList.add` does not return an Element - that method returns `undefined`

Comment: @ATD i guess , he wants to change the value of opacity of tht particular class. not just tht element.

Comment: @SandrinJoy Perhaps, but then just create a new class called, say, `info-hotspot-faint` with the same styles except the opacity and just use javascript to change the class for that element

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5753733/14216003 this might help you.

Comment: @ATD no. if we do that , then we have to change the css class of all the existing elements having tht particular clas.

Comment: @SandrinJoy no you don't.  If you create a new css class, no other element will be using it unless you have explicity said so.  As an alternative, you could create a new css class with nothing but `opacity:0.3 !important` and just add that to the new element's classList

Comment: @ATD: Tried that, and that sets the opacity to 0.3. But I want to have a dynamic info-hotspot and want to define the opacity-level.

Comment: When i set the style on WRAPPER, it sets opacity of the whole wrapper to 0.1. 
I only want to change the 0.6 in the "info-hotspot";
`.info-hotspot {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s 0.2s;
  opacity: 0.6;
}`

Comment: Then your definition of "info-hotspot" is getting confused.  It sounds like you want to create something else within a div element and apply the styles to that instead of the wrapper itself?  But your code is ONLY about a div element.

Answer (score 0):

`classList` is a [`DOMTokenList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList), that, as [documentation says](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add), has a `add` method, which returns `undefined`

You probably want:

```
wrapper.style.opacity = 0.3;
```

Comment: This makes the WHOLE wrapper have opacity 0.3. I only want to make the "info-hotspot" part-opacity 0.3

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
wrapper.style.opacity = 0.3;
```

`mytest` is undefined because `.add` method doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

```
  function createInfoHotspotElement(hotspot) {

    
    // Create wrapper element to hold icon and tooltip.
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.classList.add('hotspot');
    wrapper.classList.add('info-hotspot');
   
    // Create hotspot/tooltip header.
    var header = document.createElement('div');
    header.classList.add('info-hotspot-header');

    // Create image element.
    var iconWrapper = document.createElement('div');
    iconWrapper.classList.add('info-hotspot-icon-wrapper');
    var icon = document.createElement('img');
    icon.src = 'img/info.png';
    icon.classList.add('info-hotspot-icon');
    iconWrapper.appendChild(icon);

    // Create title element.
    var titleWrapper = document.createElement('div');
    titleWrapper.classList.add('info-hotspot-title-wrapper');
    var title = document.createElement('div');
    title.classList.add('info-hotspot-title');
    title.innerHTML = hotspot.title;
    
    titleWrapper.appendChild(title);

    // Create close element.
    var closeWrapper = document.createElement('div');
    closeWrapper.classList.add('info-hotspot-close-wrapper');
    var closeIcon = document.createElement('img');
    closeIcon.src = 'img/close.png';
    closeIcon.classList.add('info-hotspot-close-icon');
    closeWrapper.appendChild(closeIcon);

    // Construct header element.
    header.appendChild(iconWrapper);
    header.appendChild(titleWrapper);
    header.appendChild(closeWrapper);

    // Create text element.
    var text = document.createElement('div');
    text.classList.add('info-hotspot-text');
    text.innerHTML = hotspot.text;

    // Place header and text into wrapper element.
    wrapper.appendChild(header);
    wrapper.appendChild(text);

    // Create a modal for the hotspot content to appear on mobile mode.
    var modal = document.createElement('div');
    modal.innerHTML = wrapper.innerHTML;
    modal.classList.add('info-hotspot-modal');
    document.body.appendChild(modal);
 
    var toggle = function() {
      wrapper.classList.toggle('visible');
      modal.classList.toggle('visible');
    };

    // Show content when hotspot is clicked.
    wrapper.querySelector('.info-hotspot-header').addEventListener('click', toggle);

    // Hide content when close icon is clicked.
    modal.querySelector('.info-hotspot-close-wrapper').addEventListener('click', toggle);

    // Prevent touch and scroll events from reaching the parent element.
    // This prevents the view control logic from interfering with the hotspot.
    stopTouchAndScrollEventPropagation(wrapper);

    return wrapper;
  }
```

the css;

```
.info-hotspot {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s 0.2s;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the structure of your hotspot:

```
<div class="hotspot info-hotspot"> // wrapper variable
  <div class="info-hotspot-header"> // header variable
    <div class="info-hotspot-icon-wrapper"> //iconWrapper variable
      <img src="img/info.png" class="info-hotspot-icon"> // iconWrapper variable
    </div>
    <div class="info-hotspot-title-wrapper"> // titleWrapper variable
      <div class="info-hotspot-title"> // title variable
        (hotspot.title goes here)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-hotspot-close-wrapper"> // closeWrapper variable
      <img src="img/close.png" class="info-hotspot-close-icon"> // closeIcon variable
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="info-hotspot-text"> // text variable
    (hotspot.text goes here)
  </div>
</div>


<div class="info-hotspot-modal"> // modal variable
  (contents of wrapper div - BUT ONLY THE CONTENTS)
</div>
```

At this point, there are two questions:

1 - Your code only inserts the wrapper's `innerHTML` into the modal DIV - should that be either appendChild() or `outerHTML` so that you get the entire DIV and its contents?

2 - Which part of this structure actually requires the opacity style?

Comment: May I just ask what effect you are trying to achieve.  Your css class definition includes a transition which implies that you want to a a new div that fades in.  If you go to your profile page and click in the "All Actions" option, and then on one of the links back to a comment on this page, you will see that the comment is displayed in a yellowy div and that fades out to plain white.  Apart from fading in instead of out, and the fact that the comment is already there, not a new one, is that what you want to happen?

Answer (score -1):

It's not completely clear to me what you are trying to do here, but this should work:

```
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');

wrapper.class='hotspot';

wrapper.style.cssText='opacity:0.3;';

document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
```

Comment: this is to change the style of tht element. He asked to change the property of a particular css class

Comment: That’s not what I’m seeing… you can’t add/remove classes to an element that hasn’t even been created.

Comment: @SandrinJoy  Where does he says that he wants to redefine the css class itself?  If that was the case, then updating the css definition manually would do it - or, use cssRules to update through code (but that's a lot more complicated).  The implication of the question is that this particular element has the same class as all of the others BUT with the exception that it needs a different opacity value.

Comment: @ATD "In CSS I have defined the opacity as 0.6 and I want to change it to 0.3" This line

Comment: See error... "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined" ...because the element doesn't exist yet! Only after my script above can he start using Addclass/Removeclass.

Comment: @someuser999 The element exists as soon as he creates it - the very first line of code.  The problem is that his code is trying to set the new styling to the wrong thing - it needs to be on the `wrapper` object (ie, the new DIV) itself.

Comment: Unless you appendChild() it doesn't exist. End of story...

Comment: @someuser999 Then what exactly is the appendChild() appending if not an EXISTING object?

Comment: @someuser999 Even in your own code you are updating the cssText on the new DIV object BEFORE the appendChild().  You can't have it both ways!

Comment: He doesn't have an appendChild() in his script.

Comment: @someuser999 Not in the code he has provided, no, but we don't know if he has that later on.  All he has shown us is the code **up to the point of failure**.  But, whether appendChild() is there or not, the createElement function has created a new object that can be manipulated as he wants - including adding styling.

Comment: I can only go by what I see. He tried to operate on an element before an appendChild() and that's not valid and should throw a "undefined".

Comment: @someuser999  It is valid.  Most code works that way when creating a new object.  YOUR OWN CODE does that.  It has nothing to do with whether or not the new object has been appended to a parent object.  The very first line of his code creates the object.  The issue, as I and others have said, is that he is trying to apply styling to the wrong thing.

Comment: @someuser999  Also note that your code is wrong - it should be `className` not `class`

Comment: Incorrect. You can ASSIGN a value before element creation like... e.id="abc"; ...but you cannot OPERATE with changing/removing a class. There's a BIG difference between ASSIGN and OPERATE.

Comment: @someuser999  What are you on about?  `assign` gives the variable `wrapper` a new object.  Once that object has been created by the document.createElement() function, it is assigned to the variable.  That is how we create new elements.  Thereafter, you can do what you want with the object's properties or functions etc.  This has NOTHING to do with whether or not you have used appendChild as that just adds the object to a parent.

Comment: Prior to element creation, this is valid... e.id='abc'; ... but this is not... e.id='abc'.trim(); because we are calling a function (OPERATING) on a non existant element.

Comment: Seriously?  So, now you are now saying that we can't even use string functions?  If e has been assigned to a newly created element, then e.id exists, and we can use whatever method we want to assign a value to it.  We could even do: e.id = getAValue(); if we wanted to.  The createElement() function call creates the object.  Thereafter it is an object.