# Change style of tag from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know if we can change the css of a **tag** in html from javascript. i know a approach of getting all elements with that tag using `document.getElementsbyTagName` and using a for loop to change the css properties of each... however im looking for an approach which might be much more compact like this `document.getElementsbyTagName("p").style.color = "red"`
**EDIT:** using .forEach is almost the same as using a for loop.... I didnt want to use this approach as it will take time to process all of the elements especially when the pages scale to have lots of p tags.

Comment: There's no such method when you need to change the style of multiple elements. What you can do, is to wrap the wanted tags to a wrapper element, and change the class of the wrapper. In CSS you need a rule `.wrapper p {color: red;}`. Add `wrapper` class to the wrapper element when you want paragraphs with red text, and remove `wrapper` class from the wrapper element when you want the paragraphs with some original color.

Comment: is `document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(e => e.style.color='red')` more compact than whatever it is you're doing?

Comment: using .forEach is almost the same as using a for loop.... i didnt want to use this approach as it will take time to process all of the elements especially when the pages scale to have lots of p tags.

Comment: yes, it will take time ... like, a few milliseconds .... a "native" function would also take time ... everything "takes time" ... it's just whether you think saving few milliseconds is that important in the scheme of things

Comment: Use a stylesheet like I've adviced above, there's no way to set the inline style of multiple elements without iterating all those elements. You can use `body` as a wrapper element, if all the `p` elements are meant to change their color.

Answer (score 1):

This is a one liner, less than this is impossible.

```
document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(p => p.style.color = "red")
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(p => p.style.color = "red")
```

```html
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
```

Comment: the iterable that querySelectorAll returns has a native `.forEach` - so, it can be shorter :p

Comment: Cool, I thought that all the multiple selector methods did not implement the .forEach() method natively!

Comment: anything that returns a NodeList will have .forEach ... I believe what the older methods (byClassName byTagName etc), either a HTMLCollection or a NodeList, is different between browsers!

Comment: Yes all the other methods *getBy* return instances of HTMLCollection which do not have a `.forEach` method in the proto, `querySelectorAll` return a NodeList on the other hand. I don't think it's browser related, I'm just used to spread the result into an array to be safe if you want to use other array methods., for example `NodeList` instances have a native `forEach` but don't have `map` and `filter` methods !

Comment: getElementsByName returns a NodeList - as does getElementsByTagName in WebKit browsers

Comment: Then that's a pretty inconsistent behaviour to rely on, in Chrome/Edge on Windows they return HTMlCollections. I assume it's safer to spread the results into an array or to convert to an Array with `Array.from`

Comment: document.querySelectorAll, being the new kid on the block, **is** consistent though :p

Comment: Yes but always lacking .map, filter, .reduce, etc.... so basically it's almost useless :) .

Answer (score 1):

You could make a helper function that does it for you, maybe something like this:

```js
function doAll(tagName, action) {
    document.querySelectorAll(tagName).forEach(action);
}
doAll("p", element => element.style.color = "red");
```

Comment: the iterable that querySelectorAll returns has a native `.forEach`

Comment: @Bravo Thanks, I was just copying another .forEach example from further up. Wasn't sure, but edited anyways.

Comment: You could then go further and pass 3 params (tagName, propertyName, propertyValue) instead of passing  a callback :-)

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure if changing style of tags without loop is possible. Though you can change style of a class or tag by **changing properties of a stylesheet** using javascript.

Reference : [Change CSS of class in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753680/change-css-of-class-in-javascript)
MDN Docs Reference : [StyleSheetList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheetList)